# Filtering 2 highest unique values per person

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I'm stuck on a data wrangling step in my project and I was wondering if someone was able to help me.

Part of the dataframe I have is this:

| Person | month | GPI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 10 |
| 1 | 12 | 12 |
| 1 | 11 | 18 |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 | 12 |
| 2 | 8 | 14 |
| 2 | 9 | 16 |

However, I to group by Person and only keep the rows of the 2 largest unique month values. So for person 1 this would be month 12 & 11 and for person 2 this would be 10 & 9. Eventually i want to average the GPI per person.

The table should look like this

| Person | month | GPI | avg_GPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 10 | 8 |
| 1 | 12 | 7 | 8 |
| 1 | 11 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 10 | 12 | 14 |
| 2 | 9 | 16 | 14 |

Hopefully someone else can help me with this problem.

Here is the code to create the first Table:
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                  'month':[12, 12, 11, 10, 10, 8, 9],
                  'GPI':[10, 12, 18, 20, 12, 14, 16]})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your expected output dose not match you input data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with

```
s = df.groupby(['Person','month'])['GPI'].max().sort_values().groupby(level=[0]).tail(2)
out = df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['Person','month']]).isin(s.index)]
Out[66]: 
   Person  month  GPI
2       1     11   18
3       1     10   20
5       2      8   14
6       2      9   16
```

Comment: @SkipVanDerMeer happy coding ~

Answer (score 5):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html)

We can try `groupby` and `rank` to select rows corresponding to largest 2 month values per `Person`

```
df[df.groupby('Person')['month'].rank('dense', False) <= 2]
```

---

```
   Person  month  GPI
0       1     12   10
1       1     12   12
2       1     11   18
4       2     10   12
6       2      9   16
```

Comment: Should it rank by GPI?

Comment: @BENY Not sure if the OP also wants to rank by `GPI`  as he only mentioned to `keep the rows of the 2 largest unique month values`

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
df = df.groupby(['Person', 'month']).agg(list).sort_index(
    ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(2).explode('GPI')
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Person  month GPI
0       2     10  12
1       2      9  16
2       1     12  10
3       1     12  12
4       1     11  18
```